# Whitelisted azure outbound ip addresses not connecting to smtp server

Tags: asp.net-mvc, email, azure, smtp

Mostly just a question about the next steps to do to figure out why the azure test environment isn't connecting to my specified smtp server. Currently when finishing up my form, its supposed to email the information to a specific email and upon calling that I get a 500 internal server error. I've checked my solution and saw that on my personal ip, i connected and was denied access because my ip is not white listed. All of the outbound ip addresses in the azure environment are whitelisted, but i noticed when doing a ping in cmd to the test environment, I would just get the standard cloudapp.net ip. I've seen people solve this problem with a static ip. Are there other ways to do this without needing a static ip(mostly for trying to keep costs low)?

Thanks!

Comment: Do you open smtp port on Azure NSG?

Answer (score 0):

so the issue was that the outgoing ip addresses didn't match the ip address of the site. It was the external ip in custom domains that needed to be whitelisted in order to work.